# manipulating wordpress "the_content"

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a WP site. For the article page, I use `<?php the_content(); ?>` to pull in the content of the post page that I'm on.  I need to manipulate the first letter of the first paragraph. Fortunately for me, that first paragraph seems to have a unique class of `excerpt`. I'm able to make it big and change the font, etc, but an issue arises when it comes to color.

There are six separate sections on the site. Each has it's own color. I need that letter to be the appropriate color. However, at the point where it declares that first paragraph to be of class `excerpt` it's already out of my hands so I can't dynamically add in the color or a add a unique class name, etc.

Thoughts?

EDIT upon request for a little of the code:

```
<div class="postExcerpt">
<span class="author">Bob Smith</span>
    <br/><br/>
(this is where I call the_content() and it generates the following <p> tags. Oddly enough, when I Inspect Element, I see that the first one has a class of `excerpt`, but when I view source, it doesn't)
<p>Blah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah Blah</p>
<p>Blah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah Blah</p>
<p>Blah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah Blah</p>
<p>Blah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah BlahBlah Blah Blah</p>
(out of the_content() call)
```

Comment: You're going to have to inject something somewhere if you can't do what you're looking to do through the admin. Though I'm not sure what you mean when you say, _"However, at the point where it declares the first paragraph to be of class `excerpt` it's already out of my hands..."_. I think what you want to do is apply a filter to `the_content()`.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with WP filters. Would there be a way to filter it through something to replace `<p class="excerpt">` with `<p class="excerpt_$thisSection">` where `$thisSection` is my current category? Then I can just create CSS for those 6 unique classes.

Comment: I agree with @hungerstarm, you may have to add a class to those six sections and then define the color for the first character.

Comment: I also agree. My problem is I'm not sure how to add a class to one specific `<p>` that's coming back inside `the_content()`

Comment: Post some of your HTML structure - from the section level.

Comment: Can't do something like `.[unique section class] .excerpt:first-letter`?

Comment: Sadly, no. I even managed to get a replacement filter running successfully, but I discovered the oddity that, even though in the "Inspect Element" code I see it has a class of "excerpt", when I view source, there's no class of "excerpt" so it's not replacing it! *grumble* I'll keep working on it.

Comment: But you did just give me an idea...thanks!

Comment: @ReverendDovie the difference between **View Source** and **Inspect Element** is that _View Source_ shows you what the markup looks like before any DOM operations are performed on it. In fact you are viewing the document before the browser parses the document into a DOM. DOM operations are performed by JavaScript. When you _Inspect Element_ you are seeing the structure of the webpage as a DOM - which is what a webpage looks like to the browser after the browser has parsed it and run any DOM operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I did was realize that I controlled the parent element. So I dynamically renamed it in the php file to reflect the section I was in then I created CSS for each of the new sections and performed action on p:first-of-type:first-letter and it worked.